# How to add filter in custom rss feed

Tags: filters, rss, feed

I have this code for my 2 custom rss feeds:

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_feeds' );
function custom_feeds()
{
    foreach( array( 'custom1', 'custom2' ) as $name )
    {
        add_feed( $name, 
            function() use ( $name )
            {
                get_template_part( 'rss', $name );  
            }
        );
    }
}

function feedFilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_feed) {
        $query->set('cat', '7');
        $query->set('posts_per_page','5');
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','feedFilter');
```

I wanted to put filter on `custom2` only, like filter the feed by `category 7` only; But my filter is affecting all the rss feeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the source [`is_feed`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_feed/) takes a parameter, so you should be able to restrict the query by using `$query->is_feed('custom_rss2')`.